# Change Hyperlink behaviour in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, hyperlink

[image]

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <HyperlinkButton Content="Menue Item 1" FontSize="24" />
        <HyperlinkButton Content="Menue Item 2" FontSize="24" />
    </StackPanel>
```

In Silverlight, How can I change its border color on selected item.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly do you mean by "selected item", can you explain a little bit more? the hyperlink buttons are totally independent here, and they aren't inside a ListBox or anyting, so talking about "selected item" is a little confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the following into your control resources:

```
<Style TargetType="HyperlinkButton" x:name="NewHyperlinkControl">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF73A9D8" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,2,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"  /> <!-- Embedded your font size here -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                <Grid Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="UnderlineTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">  
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="UnderlineTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">  
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">  
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>  
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="UnderlineTextBlock"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        TextDecorations="Underline"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <TextBlock Canvas.ZIndex="1"
                        x:Name="DisabledOverlay"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        Foreground="#FFAAAAAA"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <ContentPresenter 
                        x:Name="contentPresenter"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and change the following line:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
```

to be something like

```
<Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Stroke="#FF00FF00" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
```

and then set your control like so:

```
    <HyperlinkButton Content="Menue Item 2" Style="{StaticResource NewHyperlinkControl}" />
```

Comment: when i changed its fill color property it gives color but it hide text how can i set color as  background

Answer (score 0):

Use [default HyperlinkButton style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296242%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to create custom HyperlinkButton style. Change "FocusVisualElement" stroke brush.